# Custom `@typedef` object or `undefined`

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I am trying to properly document a scenario that happens throughout out a program I am working in. I am unsure how to properly express the expected resolution of certain promises. Below is my attempt to mock what is happening.

There are certain api promises, outside the scope of the program that I am trying to document. I mentioned this because documenting the api methods is not an option, but rather the variable that contain the resolved values of those promises is where I'd like focus.

```js
// simplified example
function apiMethod() {
    const fail = 0;
    const response = {
        error: fail ? "error message" : undefined, // undef if no errors
        success: fail ? undefined : [ // undef if errors present
            {key01: "val01", key02: 1, key03: {"subKey01": [1, 2, 3]}},
            {key01: "val03", key02: 2, key03: {"subKey01": [4, 5, 6]}}
        ]
    };
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(response), 250));
}
```

```js
(async () => {
    /**
     * @typedef {object} thing
     * @property {string} key01
     * @property {number} key02
     * @property {{subKey02: string[]}} key03
     */
    /**
     * @type {Promise<{success: thing[]|undefined, error: string|undefined}>}
     */
    const myVar = await apiMethod();
    console.log(myVar.key01);
})();
```

This seems to work mostly well, but where I am getting stuck on is expressing that the `success` property *could be undefined* under certain circumstances. Right now this is how the vscode tooltip looks when hovering the `myVar`;

```js
const myVar: Promise<{
    success: thing[];
    error: string | undefined;
}>
```

*Note the missing `undefined` for success*

This is how the vscode tooltip looks when hovering `thing` in the `@type` expression:

```js
type thing = {
    key01: string;
    key02: number;
    key03: {
        subKey02: string[];
    };
}
```

**Questions:**

1. Is is possible to express that `success` will be an array of `thing` objects **or undefined**? When using `typedef` it doesn't seem like I can do this.
2. Right now it only seems possible to see the exploded view of the `thing` object when hovering `thing` in the `@type` expression. When I hover `myVar` it simply shows that success will be an array of `thing`s. Is it possible show this "exploded" view of `thing` when hovering `myVar`, whilst still using `@typedef`?